# Output percentage of lines read

Tags: java

I have a method which reads all the lines in a text file, and I want to output the current percentage of the file which has been read. I've managed to do this, however, it outputs the percentage every time I read a new line, so the output looks like this:

```
0.0% read.
0.0% read.
0.0% read.
1.0% read.
1.0% read.
1.0% read.
```

And so on...
I want it to just output every time it changes from 0 to 1, from 1 to 2 or similar.
Here's the relevant piece of the code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
String line = reader.readLine();
// Counts total number of lines
BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
int totalLines = 0;
while (reader2.readLine() != null) {
    totalLines++;
}
// read all lines from file
int lineNumber = 1;
while (line != null) {
    float percent = lineNumber * 100f / totalLines;
    double x = Math.round(percent);
    System.out.println(x + "% read.");
    line = reader.readLine();
    lineNumber++;
}
```

Comment: print only when the currently computed value is different than the last notified/ printed value?

Comment: Just check for _every time it changes from 0 to 1, from 1 to 2 or similar_.

Comment: Have you tried using bytes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double x = 0;
while(line != null) {

    float percent = lineNumber * 100f / totalLines;
    if (Math.round(percent) != x) {
         System.out.println(x + "% read.");
         x = Math.round(percent);
    }
    line = reader.readLine();

    lineNumber++;   
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Store the previous value**

In the code snippet below, I'm assuming a float variable, `previousPercent`. You can declare this at the top of your loop. Update `previousPercent` with the new value on each loop. When two values differ in a loop, output the value, otherwise simply update `previousPercent`.

```
float percent = (float)Math.floor(lineNumber * 100f / totalLines);
// Compute your percentage.
if(percent != previousPercent)
{
    // Output if different from the last time.
    System.out.println(percent + "% read");
}
// Update the percentage.
previousPercent = percent;
```

**A note on your percentages**

As mentioned in the comments, it's better to round the percentages. This is because the tiniest change will result in an output. The reason for using `Math.floor()` and not `Math.round()` is because, let's say you've read `6.7%` of a file. You can justify saying `6% read` but you have not read `7%`.

Comment: You need to round `percent` or use `int`. Otherwise it will almost always change when `lineNumber` changes.

Comment: `floor(double)` returns `double`. There are no `floor(float)`.

Comment: `floor(float)` is automatically expanded to `floor(double)`. And yeah, I added a cast to the return type.

Answer (score 2):

To *make it work* , you have to check the current percentage against the one from the previous iteration;
To *make it work **better***, you should calculate the percentage on *bytes*, not *lines*;

Using bytes you will:

- prevent loading / reading the file twice, that is almost **doubling** your execution time;
- provide a more accurate percentage by using real bytes read for each line (one big line may count as 100 small lines, etc);

Run this on a 100MB file, and check out the execution time;

(note that the first method is carrying the JVM warm-up too)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Date;

public class FilePercentageTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        File file = new File("D:/test.txt");

        showPercentageByBytes(file);
        showPercentageByLines(file);

    }

    private static void showPercentageByBytes(File file) throws Exception{
        long start = new Date().getTime();          
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));               
        long totalBytes = file.length();                    
        long bytesRead = 0;
        int previousPercent = 0;
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {          
            bytesRead+=line.length();
            int percent = (int)(bytesRead * 100 / totalBytes);          
            if (previousPercent<percent){
                System.out.println(percent + "% read.");            
                previousPercent = percent;
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
        }       
        long end = new Date().getTime();            
        System.out.println(end - start + " milliseconds ");
    }


    private static void showPercentageByLines(File file) throws Exception{
        long start = new Date().getTime();          
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
        int totalLines = 0;
        int previousPercent = 0;
        while (reader2.readLine() != null) {
            totalLines++;
        }
        int lineNumber = 1;
        while (line != null) {
            int percent = lineNumber * 100 / totalLines;
            if (previousPercent<percent){
                System.out.println(percent + "% read.");            
                previousPercent = percent;
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
            lineNumber++;
        }       
        long end = new Date().getTime();            
        System.out.println(end - start + " milliseconds ");
    }
}
```